# Arcanist/Phabricator crashes on diff update

Tags: diff, review, phabricator, arcanist

I have a problem with Arcanist with the following command
arc diff --nounit --nolint --update D1434 --encoding ISO-8859-1 c5b9c50e55aefa013d5a38354a78e91b64f3b195

This command worked fine a few minutes ago before I installed the software sourceTree.

Now arcanist asks if I want to amend my untracked files (like before) which I answer with no.
the next step usual was that arcanist askt if i want to add sprcific reviers.

now it just writes the worde "Provide" on the bash and whatever I type, I get the following message 
bash: line 0: read: `abort:': not a valid identifier
Usage Exception: User aborted the workflow.

I already tried to copy the original arcanist files in the installation folder and made a new installation of git, but it didnt help.

Does anyone know the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was the git config at the following entries

```
core.autocrlf=input
core.autocrlf=true
core.autocrlf=input
```

probably sourcetree added the 3rd line. after removing the last "core.autocrlf=input" arcanist ist working again

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem. Repeating the same action on Linux, I found that arc was to ask:

Provide explanation for skipping lint or press Enter to abort:

but somehow only

Provide

appear on the screen. Don't use --nolint, or type something.